# How to scale individual SVG elements with jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a SVG with randomly dispersed squares on the page that scale up when the user scrolls past a certain point.
The issue I am having is that once the squares scale, it creates a horizontal scroll bar as if the entire SVG block scales, rather than the individual elements.

Is it possible to target each individual `rect` to scale in place with an easing motion rather than bluntly changing size (to give the impression that it's growing) so that it also doesn't stretch out the page, and then once the user continues to scroll, it reverts back to the original size?

Here is my: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmkq5w5z/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="move-wrapper">

<svg class="enlarge" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="82 -117 1363 770" style="enable-background:new 82 -117 1363 770;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
  .st0{fill:none;stroke:#A7A9AC;stroke-width:5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<rect x="153" y="-34" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="335.5" y="55.5" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="529.5" y="343.1" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="153.6" y="464.4" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="976.5" y="166.4" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="1288.3" y="-12.1" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="941.9" y="575.3" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
<rect x="1355.9" y="434.9" class="st0" width="22.1" height="22.1"/>
</svg>

</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.move-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

.spacer {
  height:500px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition >= 20) {
      $(".enlarge").css({"-moz-transform": "scale(1.5,1.5)", "webkit-transform": "scale(1.5,1.5)"});
    $(this).off('scroll');
    }

    if (scrollPosition >= 40) {
      $(".enlarge").css({"-moz-transform": "scale(1,1)", "webkit-transform": "scale(1,1)"});
        $(this).off('scroll');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the .enlarge class to each `rect` instead of the entire SVG element?

Comment: I have tried it, however it just turns my squares into solid black squares and removes the stroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/_jered/0yy0nLam/

- Move stylings into CSS whenever possible.
- Wrap each `rect` in an `svg` to control positioning independent of scale.
- Offset each `rect` by half it's width so that the transform is centered.

One thing to beware of is that I'm not sure if `x` and `y` attributes are part of the spec for `svg` elements. Seems to work in Chrome but not might be consistent across browsers. A more solid approach which I was too lazy to implement was to do a CSS transform instead.